# Problems with GoogleSheet API and trying to write unicode characters

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, unicode, google-api

I'm trying to use Google Sheet as some sort of a database for my little school project.
Reading has been going quite well, both ASCII (english) and UNICODE (vietnamese) characters.

The problem lies in trying to write UNICODE (vietnamese) strings into cells (ASCII - english works fine)

```
values = "Nguyễn Văn A"
writeParams = { spreadsheetId: Sheet_ID, range: range, valueInputOption: "RAW", resource: { values: values, majorDimension : majorDimension } };

req = await gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.update(writeParams);
return req;
```

The result is "Nguyá»…n VÄƒn A".

Is the problem being that Google API Client sends the Unicode string as an ASCII one? If so then how can I fix it? Thanks for any help, I appreciate them greatly.

Comment: O don't use Google Sheets however you face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): `"Nguyễn Văn A".encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp1252')` returns `'Nguyá»…n VÄƒn A'`…

Comment: Try `values=[["Nguyễn Văn A"]]`